# Is it possible to define controller specific routes in that specific controller instead of placing the routes in web.php

Tags: php, laravel

In my search for clean code i'm working with single action controllers in laravel. In those single action controllers i have a __invoke and a __construct. They look like this:

```
 public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware(['permission:create documents']);
    }


public function __invoke($id)
{
    $machine = Machine::find($id);
    return view('document.create', compact('machine'));
}
```

And i define the create document route in the web.php file like this:

```
Route::get('/document/create/{id}', CreateDocument::class)->name('document.create');
```

Because i use single action controllers this results in a lot of routes in the web.php file and this causes a problem that its hard to find routes sometimes.

Is it possible to define the route within the __construct function of a controller instead of placing it in the web.php file? And if its possible how can i do that.

I've researched if it is possible and can't find a awnser to my question.

*I don't know is StackOverflow is the best place to ask this question, if i should place it somewhere else instead of StackOverflow please let me know.*

Comment: dont use laravel. but everything is possible if you put in the effort. You'll have to change a lot in the `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class`  map method

Comment: Don't use laravel is a bit of a bold statement. Can you clearify your comment? What should i use instead?

Comment: Read the comment again, i already gave you a lead on how to do it.

Comment: by that i meant, if you dont want to use the structure proposed by a framework, then dont use the framework, cause its structure is what defines it. You would have less work and bugs starting from a bunch of packages and create your own framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u are having problem finding routes and you want to place your routes somewhere else rather than web.php Follow the steps

Step1:
Go to RouteServiceProvider in App\Providers 
and inside there after mapApiRoutes() just define a function

```
public function mapCustomWebRoutes()
{
     Route::middleware('web') // or any other middleware if u want to use
         ->namespace($this->namespace) // By default namespace is define as the 
          // App\Http\Controllers in the top of this file. If u want to change           
           // can change it
         ->group(base_path('routes/new_web.php')); // new_web is the name of 
           // another file inside routes
}
```

Then in the map function call this function like this

```
public function map()
{
      $this->mapApiRoutes();
      $this->mapWebRoutes();
      // calling the function 
      $this->mapCustomWebRoutes();
}
```

Now in your routes folder create a file called new_web.php
and Now you can define your routes there like this

```
<?php

   Route::get('/something','SomethingController@something');
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will look into that. Just to check, without rewriting the RouteServiceProvider i cant place the routes in a controller?

Comment: You cant place your routes in controller . But you can have clouse function inside the routes inplace of controller.
Mark it right after you done